# Tables with the same height and width

Tags: tabularray

How can I make these three tables the `same width and height` and the `width of the first column of each table the same`?

Also, how do I display the "Product" table `just to the right` of the "Sum" table? The minipage environment doesn't seem to work for me!

[image]

MWE  :

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,array,cellspace,tabularray,tabularx,tabvar,tikz,xcolor}
\UseTblrLibrary{varwidth}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
column{1}=36pt,
rows = {abovesep=4.5pt,belowsep=4.5pt},
columns = {leftsep=9pt,rightsep=9pt},
colspec={lcccccc},
cell{1}{1}={c},
hline{2,3,4} = {1-7}{black},
vline{2} = {black},
cell{1}{1} = {green!30},
stretch=-1,
measure=vbox}
\SetCell[r=1,c=1]{c} Somme \\
$\lim_{} f$ & $\ell$ & $\ell$ & $\ell$ & + $\infty$ & - $\infty$ & + $\infty$ \\
$\lim_{} g$ & $\ell '$ & + $\infty$ & - $\infty$ & + $\infty$ & - $\infty$ & - $\infty$ \\
$\lim_{} f + g$ & $\ell + \ell '$ & + $\infty$ & - $\infty$ & + $\infty$ & - $\infty$ & $?$ \\
\end{tblr}

\vspace{.3cm}

\begin{tblr}{
column{1}=36pt,
rows = {abovesep=4.5pt,belowsep=4.5pt},
columns = {leftsep=9pt,rightsep=9pt},
colspec={lcccc},
cell{1}{1}={c},
hline{2,3,4} = {1-7}{black},
vline{2} = {black},
cell{1}{1} = {blue!30},
stretch=-1,
measure=vbox}
\SetCell[r=1,c=1]{c} Produit \\
$\lim_{} f$ & $\ell$ & $\ell \neq 0 $ & $\infty$ & $0$ \\
$\lim_{} g$ & $\ell '$ & $\infty$ & $\infty$ & $\infty$ \\
$\lim_{} f \times g$ & $\ell \times \ell '$ & $\infty$ & $\infty$ & $?$ \\
\end{tblr}

\vspace{.3cm}

\begin{tblr}{
column{1}=36pt,
rows = {abovesep=4.5pt,belowsep=4.5pt},
columns = {leftsep=9pt,rightsep=9pt},
colspec={lcccccc},
cell{1}{1}={c},
hline{2,3,4} = {1-7}{black},
vline{2} = {black},
cell{1}{1} = {purple!30},
stretch=-1,
measure=vbox}
\SetCell[r=1,c=1]{c} Quotient \\
$\lim_{} f$ & $\ell$ & $\ell \neq 0$ & $\ell$ & $\infty$ & $\infty$ & $0$ \\
$\lim_{} g$ & $\ell ' \neq 0$ & $0$ & $\infty$ & $\ell$ & $\infty$ & $0$\\
$\lim_{} \dfrac{f}{g}$ & $\dfrac{\ell}{\ell '}$ & $\infty$ & $0$ & $\infty$ & ? & ? \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

**Mix of proposed solutions, thanks guys!**

```
\noindent\begin{tblr}{
        rows = {abovesep=4.5pt, belowsep=4.5pt},
        rowspec={m{4mm} | t{10mm}  | t{10mm}  | t{10mm} },
        columns = {leftsep=4pt, rightsep=4pt,26pt},
        column{1}=1.5cm,
        colspec={lcccccc},
        cell{1}{1}={c},
        hline{2,3,4} = {1-7}{black},
        vline{2} = {black},
        cell{1}{1} = {green!30},
        stretch=-1,
    %   measure=\vbox
    }
    \SetCell[r=1,c=1]{c} Somme \\
    $\lim_{} f$ & $\ell$ & $\ell$ & $\ell$ & $+\infty$ & $-\infty$ & $+\infty$ \\
    $\lim_{} g$ & $\ell '$ & $+\infty$ & $-\infty$ & $+\infty$ & $-\infty$ & $-\infty$ \\
    $\lim_{} f + g$ & $\ell + \ell '$ & $+\infty$ & $-\infty$ & $+\infty$ & $-\infty$ & $?$ \\
\end{tblr}

\vspace{.3cm}

\noindent\begin{tblr}{
        rows = {abovesep=4.5pt,belowsep=4.5pt},
        rowspec={m{4mm} | t{10mm}  | t{10mm}  | t{10mm} },
        columns = {leftsep=4pt, rightsep=4pt,26pt},
        column{1}=1.5cm,
        colspec={lcccccc},
        cell{1}{1}={c},
        hline{2,3,4} = {1-6}{black},
        vline{2} = {black},
        cell{1}{1} = {purple!30},
        stretch=-1,
%       measure=\vbox
}
    \SetCell[r=1,c=1]{c} Quotient \\
    $\lim_{} f$ & $\ell$ & $\ell \neq 0$ & $\ell$ & $\infty$ & $\infty$ & $0$ \\
    $\lim_{} g$ & $\ell ' \neq 0$ & $0$ & $\infty$ & $\ell$ & $\infty$ & $0$\\
    $\lim_{} \dfrac{f}{g}$ & $\dfrac{\ell}{\ell '}$ & $\infty$ & $0$ & $\infty$ & $?$ & $?$ \\
\end{tblr}
\hspace{.3cm}
\begin{tblr}{
        rows = {abovesep=4.5pt,belowsep=4.5pt},
        rowspec={m{4mm} | t{10mm}  | t{10mm}  | t{10mm} },
        columns = {leftsep=4pt, rightsep=4pt,26pt},
        column{1}=1.5cm,
        colspec={lcccc},
        cell{1}{1}={c},
        hline{2,3,4} = {1-7}{black},
        vline{2} = {black},
        cell{1}{1} = {blue!30},
        stretch=-1,
%       measure=\vbox
    }
    \SetCell[r=1,c=1]{c} Produit \\
    $\lim_{} f$ & $\ell$ & $\ell \neq 0 $ & $\infty$ & $0$ \\
    $\lim_{} g$ & $\ell '$ & $\infty$ & $\infty$ & $\infty$ \\
    $\lim_{} f \times g$ & $\ell \times \ell '$ & $\infty$ & $\infty$ & $?$ \\
\end{tblr}
```

Comment: For the second question, you need to delete (or comment out) the empty lines around  `\vspace{.3cm}`. LaTeX is interpreting that as a command to start a new paragraph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You asked,

> how do I display the "Product" table just to the right of the "Sum" table?

I can't see a good use case for `tblr` environments here. I'd use three `array` environments instead -- with the big advantage of not having to provide so many `$` symbols. Also, don't be afraid to use inline fraction notation when doing so is eminently called for.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page parameters suitably
%% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{array}    % for 'w' column type
\usepackage{xcolor}   % color support
\usepackage{colortbl} % for '\cellcolor' macro 
% Determine widths of (a) header column and (b) data columns:
\newlength\lenA  \settowidth\lenA{\textsf{Quotient}}
\newlength\lenB  \settowidth\lenB{$\ell'\ne0$}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
$\begin{array}{wl{\lenA} | *{6}{wc{\lenB}} @{}}
\cellcolor{green!30} \textsf{Somme} & \\
\hline
\lim f & \ell & \ell & \ell & +\infty & -\infty & +\infty \\
\hline
\lim g & \ell' & +\infty & -\infty & +\infty & -\infty & -\infty \\
\hline
\lim f{+}g& \ell+\ell' & +\infty & +\infty & +\infty & +\infty & \text{?} 
\end{array}$
\hfill % maximize the horizontal separation
$\begin{array}{wl{\lenA} | *{4}{wc{\lenB}} @{}}
\cellcolor{blue!30} \textsf{Produit} & \\
\hline
\lim f & \ell & \ell\ne0 & \infty & 0  \\
\hline
\lim g & \ell' & \infty & \infty & \infty  \\
\hline
\lim f{\times}g& \ell\times\ell' & \infty & \infty & \text{?} 
\end{array}$

\bigskip
$\begin{array}{wl{\lenA} | *{6}{wc{\lenB}} @{}}
\cellcolor{purple!30} \textsf{Quotient} & \\
\hline
\lim f & \ell & \ell\ne0 & \ell & \infty & \infty & 0 \\
\hline
\lim g  & \ell'\ne0 & 0 & \infty & \ell & \infty & 0 \\
\hline
\lim f{/}g& \ell/\ell' & \infty & 0 & \infty & \text{?} & \text{?} 
\end{array}$
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this is what you want:

[image]

You need to delete the empty lines between the tables (which cause a new paragraph to start).

After that, `columns = {leftsep=4pt, rightsep=4pt, 9mm}` will fix all columns at `9mm`. To make the first column special, place `column{1}=36pt` *after* the `columns` command.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,array,cellspace,tabularray,tabularx,tabvar,tikz,xcolor}
\UseTblrLibrary{varwidth}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tblr}{
rows = {abovesep=4.5pt, belowsep=4.5pt},
columns = {leftsep=4pt, rightsep=4pt, 9mm},
column{1}=36pt,
colspec={lcccccc},
cell{1}{1}={c},
hline{2,3,4} = {1-7}{black},
vline{2} = {black},
cell{1}{1} = {green!30},
stretch=-1,
measure=vbox}
\SetCell[r=1,c=1]{c} Somme \\
$\lim_{} f$ & $\ell$ & $\ell$ & $\ell$ & + $\infty$ & $-\infty$ & $+\infty$ \\
$\lim_{} g$ & $\ell '$ & $+\infty$ & $-\infty$ & $+\infty$ & $-\infty$ & $-\infty$ \\
$\lim_{} f + g$ & $\ell + \ell '$ & $+\infty$ & $-\infty$ & $+\infty$ & $-\infty$ & $?$ \\
\end{tblr}
\quad
\begin{tblr}{
rows = {abovesep=4.5pt,belowsep=4.5pt},
columns = {leftsep=4pt, rightsep=4pt, 9mm},
column{1}=36pt,
colspec={lcccc},
cell{1}{1}={c},
hline{2,3,4} = {1-7}{black},
vline{2} = {black},
cell{1}{1} = {blue!30},
stretch=-1,
measure=vbox}
\SetCell[r=1,c=1]{c} Produit \\
$\lim_{} f$ & $\ell$ & $\ell \neq 0 $ & $\infty$ & $0$ \\
$\lim_{} g$ & $\ell '$ & $\infty$ & $\infty$ & $\infty$ \\
$\lim_{} f \times g$ & $\ell \times \ell '$ & $\infty$ & $\infty$ & $?$ \\
\end{tblr}

\vspace{4mm}
\noindent\begin{tblr}{
rows = {abovesep=4.5pt,belowsep=4.5pt},
columns = {leftsep=4pt, rightsep=4pt, 9mm},
column{1}=36pt,
colspec={lcccccc},
cell{1}{1}={c},
hline{2,3,4} = {1-7}{black},
vline{2} = {black},
cell{1}{1} = {purple!30},
stretch=-1,
measure=vbox}
\SetCell[r=1,c=1]{c} Quotient \\
$\lim_{} f$ & $\ell$ & $\ell \neq 0$ & $\ell$ & $\infty$ & $\infty$ & $0$ \\
$\lim_{} g$ & $\ell ' \neq 0$ & $0$ & $\infty$ & $\ell$ & $\infty$ & $0$\\
$\lim_{} \dfrac{f}{g}$ & $\dfrac{\ell}{\ell '}$ & $\infty$ & $0$ & $\infty$ & ? & ? \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you!

I changed the settings slightly and got something almost compliant, but there is still a space difference (updated post).

Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: @Sacha: I cannot duplicate your result. There is no space difference when I compile the code. Replace `\quad` with `\hspace{-3mm}` to test. Checked with magnification at 10000%. Maybe this is just an issue with your pdf viewer.

Comment: Whatever else you do, there should be no space between the `+` and `-` symbols and the associated `\infty` symbol. Also, I wouldn't use a text-mode "dash" symbol instead of a math-mode "minus" symbol to denote negative values.

Comment: @Mico: Fixed. Didn't notice that in the original code.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I finally got the result I wanted. Code updated above.

Answer (score 2):

something like this??

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray,xcolor,mathtools}
\begin{document}
    
\noindent\begin{tblr}{
        rows = {abovesep=4.5pt, belowsep=4.5pt},
        rowspec={m{4mm} | t{10mm}  | t{10mm}  | t{10mm} },
        columns = {leftsep=4pt, rightsep=4pt,25pt},
        column{1}=1.5cm,
        colspec={XXXXXX},
        cell{1}{1}={c},
        hline{2,3,4} = {1-7}{black},
        vline{2} = {black},
        cell{1}{1} = {green!30},
        stretch=-1,
    %   measure=\vbox
    }
    \SetCell[r=1,c=1]{c} Somme \\
    $\lim_{} f$ & $\ell$ & $\ell$ & $\ell$ & + $\infty$ & - $\infty$ & + $\infty$ \\
    $\lim_{} g$ & $\ell '$ & + $\infty$ & - $\infty$ & + $\infty$ & - $\infty$ & - $\infty$ \\
    $\lim_{} f + g$ & $\ell + \ell '$ & + $\infty$ & - $\infty$ & + $\infty$ & - $\infty$ & $?$ \\
\end{tblr}


\noindent
\begin{tblr}{
        rows = {abovesep=4.5pt,belowsep=4.5pt},
        rowspec={m{4mm} | t{10mm}  | t{10mm}  | t{10mm} },
        columns = {leftsep=4pt, rightsep=4pt,25pt},
        column{1}=1.5cm,
        colspec={XXXX},
        cell{1}{1}={c},
        hline{2,3,4} = {1-7}{black},
        vline{2} = {black},
        cell{1}{1} = {blue!30},
        stretch=-1,
%       measure=\vbox
    }
    \SetCell[r=1,c=1]{c} Produit \\
    $\lim_{} f$ & $\ell$ & $\ell \neq 0 $ & $\infty$ & $0$ \\
    $\lim_{} g$ & $\ell '$ & $\infty$ & $\infty$ & $\infty$ \\
    $\lim_{} f \times g$ & $\ell \times \ell '$ & $\infty$ & $\infty$ & $?$ \\
\end{tblr}

\noindent\begin{tblr}{
        rows = {abovesep=4.5pt,belowsep=4.5pt},
        rowspec={m{4mm} | t{10mm}  | t{10mm}  | t{10mm} },
        columns = {leftsep=4pt, rightsep=4pt,25pt},
        column{1}=1.5cm,
        colspec={XXXXXX},
        cell{1}{1}={c},
        hline{2,3,4} = {1-6}{black},
        vline{2} = {black},
        cell{1}{1} = {purple!30},
        stretch=-1,
%       measure=vbox
}
    \SetCell[r=1,c=1]{c} Quotient \\
    $\lim_{} f$ & $\ell$ & $\ell \neq 0$ & $\ell$ & $\infty$ & $\infty$ & $0$ \\
    $\lim_{} g$ & $\ell ' \neq 0$ & $0$ & $\infty$ & $\ell$ & $\infty$ & $0$\\
    $\lim_{} \dfrac{f}{g}$ & $\dfrac{\ell}{\ell '}$ & $\infty$ & $0$ & $\infty$ & ? & ? \\
\end{tblr}  
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think the OP wants the second table to be next to, rather than below, the first one. Also, I'm pretty sure that (a) one should avoid a line break in the `$\ell' \neq 0$` cell in the third table and (b) the contents of the dsta columns should be centered rather than left-aligned.

Answer (score 1):

I propose a command with 3 parameters

```
    % #1--> color of the title (option)
    % #2 --> number of columns 6 par défaut
    % #3 --> the table
```

With mode=math the $ are not necessary

EDIT2:  To solve the overfull problem, I changed the width of the first column and I propose to take a measure in em

```
    \documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularray}
%\UseTblrLibrary{varwidth}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \sacha { O{} O{6} +m }
  {     % #1--> couleur (option)
        % #2 --> nombre de colonnes 6 par défaut
        % #3 --> le tableau
    \begin{tblr}{
      rows = {abovesep=4.5pt,belowsep=4.5pt,ht=1.5\baselineskip},
      columns = {leftsep=9pt,rightsep=9pt},
      colspec = {
        Q[l,wd=4em,mode=math]
        *{#2}{Q[c,wd=2.6em,mode=math]}
    },
      cell{1}{1}={c,mode=text,bg=#1},
      hline{2-4} = {1-Z}{black},
      vline{2} = {black},
      %stretch=-1,
      %measure=vbox
      }
      #3
      \end{tblr}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\sacha[green!30]{
\SetCell[r=1,c=1]{c} Somme \\
\lim_{} f  &  \ell  &  \ell  &  \ell  & +  \infty  & -  \infty  & +  \infty  \\
\lim_{} g  &  \ell '  & +  \infty  & -  \infty  & +  \infty  & -  \infty  & -  \infty  \\
\lim_{} f + g  &  \ell + \ell '  & +  \infty  & -  \infty  & +  \infty  & -  \infty  &  ? }
\quad\sacha[blue!30][4]{
\SetCell[r=1,c=1]{c} Produit \\
\lim_{} f  &  \ell  &  \ell \neq 0   &  \infty  &  0  \\
\lim_{} g  &  \ell '  &  \infty  &  \infty  &  \infty  \\
\lim_{} f \times g  &  \ell \times \ell '  &  \infty  &  \infty  &  ? 
}

\smallskip
\sacha[purple!30]{
\SetCell[r=1,c=1]{c} Quotient \\
\lim_{} f  &  \ell  &  \ell \neq 0  &  \ell  &  \infty  &  \infty  &  0  \\
\lim_{} g  &  \ell ' \neq 0  &  0  &  \infty  &  \ell  &  \infty  &  0 \\
\lim_{} \dfrac{f}{g}  &  \dfrac{\ell}{\ell '}  &  \infty  &  0  &  \infty  & ? & ?}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi man, I have errors during compilation...

Comment: @Sacha with texlive2022 it work fine. You can test with https://texlive.net/run